# Pad integer after hyphen

Tags: python-2.7

How do you pad a number 12345-9 to display as 12345-09? I tried split and replace but they don't work on integers. If I convert it to a string, it gets rid of the numbers after the hyphen.

Comment: Split on the hyphen, pad the number, and join them?

Comment: How is it not already a string?

Comment: Show what you have done, and describe more precisely what's wrong with it.

Comment: Is the input always going to be seven digits long?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Adam said, split on the hyphen, pad the number, and then rejoin.

```
s = "12345-9"
sp = s.split("-")
sp[1] = "%02d" % int(sp[1])
s = "-".join(sp)
print s
```

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> s = '12345-9'
>>> '%s-%02i' % tuple(int(v) for v in s.split('-'))
'12345-09'
```